# Change Docky icons for Wine applications?

Tags: wine, icons, docky

is there a way of customizing the icons shown in Docky for wine applications (including starter and running applications)?

Most Windows programs have icons with too low resolution by default, so I'd like to assign better icons to them.

Thanks in advance!
YSN

Comment: This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with creating a new launcher (for example on your desktop), setting the icon to one you like and then dragging that launcher onto Docky?

Just tried it and it works here.

Edit to try and help, here's the source of my modified launcher:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Darkstar One
Exec=bash -c "cd \\"~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/GOG.com/Darkstar One\\" & wine explorer /desktop=DarkstarOne,1920x1200 DarkStarOne.exe"
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Path=/home/oli/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files/GOG.com/Darkstar One/
Icon=/home/oli/Desktop/darkstar.jpg
```

`/home/oli/Desktop/darkstar.jpg` is the location of the new icon. But this does work for me with Docky 2.0.7. I even tried launching it and the icon remained the new one.

Comment: Hi Oli! Unfortunately your solution does not work for me. If I start a wine application from a starter created the way you described, there appears a second (low-res windows) icon in Docky. Thanks for responding anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information Oli. It still doesn't work for me, but maybe it is just something about my system (Maverick-amd64 with Docky 2.1.0). CU

Comment: Maverick64 here too. Are you using a PPA version? Perhaps it's a regression. Try reverting with ppa-purge and test again.

Comment: Yes, I had been using a PPA version. I'm afraid, ppa-purge back to 2.0.7. did not help on my system as well. I am giving up on this issue, since it is just a matter of cosmetics. Thanks for your kind help, Oli!